# Variable of AppDelegate used as global variable doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, class

I would like to use my AppDelegate to store a object which will be accessible to any other classes. I've declared this AppDelegate like this :

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    MyClass *tracker;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ICViewController *viewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyClass *tracker;

@end
```

I synthesize tracker and in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: i set one NSString in that object like this :

```
self.tracker = [[MyClass alloc] init];
self.tracker.testGlobal = @"global funguje";
```

When i need to access tracker somewhere else in some other class i use this code :

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
MyClass *trackerTEST = appDelegate.tracker;
NSLog(@"TEST : %@",trackerTEST.testGlobal);
```

The problem is that testGlobal is NULL. What am I doing wrong? Also here are class files for MyClass :

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *testGlobal;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *testGlobal;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize testGlobal = _testGlobal;
@end
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: You say `testGlobal` is nil, but are you sure that `trackerTEST` and `appDelegate` are not also nil?

Comment: well just found out that appDelegate is fine, but trackerTEST is nil...hmmm...what am i doing wrong here? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is being called by adding a `NSLog(@"...")`. If `trackerTEST` is nil, it was possibly not correctly initialized.

Comment: THANK YOU! I finally figure it out thanks to you...it was really stupid mistake :) i was initializing tracker at the end of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: , which is after i was using... grrr :) thanks, really :)

Comment: You are welcome. I would suggest to relocate the initialization to your `init` method. But i am not as skilled to be sure if thats a decent solution. :D

Answer (score 4):

maybe I'm answer to late but, you can take a look at the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects.

Here is an ObjC implementation: http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

Comment: defiitely not late... its a good answer ;) but then i decided to rather use this method...singletons are too complex for me in this case... but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    MyClass *tracker;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ICViewController *viewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) MyClass *tracker;

@end
```

Why you have @property tracker and var tracker?

Try to remove `MyClass *tracker;` property only should be enough.

Comment: well i was desperate, so i tried to add it there :) but removing it didn't help, it's still nil... :/

Answer (score 0):

Change `@synthesize testGlobal = _testGlobal;` to `@synthesize testGlobal;` and try again.

Comment: didn't help neither... :/ the problem is that the object i get from appdelegate is nil...